# scrapy install no .bat file

Tags: python, batch-file, installation, scrapy

I'm in a windows 10 environment and have installed scrapy.  When I try to run it however, it is still not recognized. My understanding is that I need a .bat file in the python\scripts folder.  I've not had any success running the solutions found in other questions.

```
@echo off

setlocal

"%~dp0..\python" "%~dp0scrapy" %*

endlocal
```

did not work.

I was able to find the scrapy file in the \lib\site-packages path. But don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the [installation guide](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows), the only additional thing I did (if you are using virtualenv) was to install the pywin32 inside my virtualenv using easy_install. Also double check your `PATH` environment variable and (just in case) restart your Windows.

Comment: Yes - I followed installation guide which included installing pywin32.  PATH is good.  I did not restart - guess that never hurts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The restart itself did not work, however I did an uninstall and reinstall and it must have installed what was needed!